# How does MongoDB calculate the size of a document?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB there is the maximum size of 16 MByte per document. Does this size limit include sub-documents?

In other words: Are the 16 MByte per document including its sub-documents, or is it 16 MByte per document and each sub-document counts as an own document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is 16MB limit for the whole structure, including sub-documents.

Keep in mind that what you call sub-documents, MongoDB sees as regular values. From its perspective, they are no different than, say, strings. Just values.